# Неккоректно работает telegram бот

Tags: python, api, telegram, бот, telebot

Есть 2 файла: `bot.py` и `feedback.py`. Не понимаю, почему не срабатывает последний блок, в `bot.py`, `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message...`? Если знаете, хотя бы где прочитать, пожалуйста помогите

**bot.py**:

```
import telebot
import feedback
token = "Здесь токен"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    keyboard.row('/start')
    keyboard.row('Команда 1', 'Команда 2', 'Команда 3')
    keyboard.row('Обратная связь')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                     'Добро пожаловать...',
                     reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text != '':
        try:
            if message.text == 'Обратная связь':
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ваше имя:')
                feedback.set_state(message.from_user.id, feedback.States.S_ENTER_FIRSTNAME)
        except:
            return False
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: feedback.get_state(message.from_user.id) == feedback.States.S_ENTER_FIRSTNAME)
def user_entering_firstname(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите фамилию:")
    feedback.set_state(message.from_user.id, feedback.States.S_ENTER_LASTNAME)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

**feedback.py**:

```
import dbm
from enum import Enum


id_state = dbm.open('dbm/dbm_id_state', flag='c')

class States(Enum):
    S_START = "0"  # Начало нового диалога
    S_ENTER_FIRSTNAME = "1"
    S_ENTER_LASTNAME = "2"
    S_SEND_QUESTION = "3"

def get_state(user_id):
    id_state = dbm.open('dbm/dbm_id_state', flag='c')
    try:
        return id_state[user_id]
    except:
        return States.S_START

def set_state(user_id, new_state):
    id_state = dbm.open('dbm/dbm_id_state', flag='c')
    try:
        id_state[user_id] = new_state
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: В каком смысле не работает? Ошибку выдает, неправильное поведение? Укажите это в вопросе. Если ошибка, то добавьте трейсбэк

Comment: Уже решил через reply_to() и register_next_step_handler()